# VB Datatable select is character a letter

Tags: vb.net, datatable

In VB, I am trying to do a datatable.select statement.  I had one where i needed to check if the 4th character of a string was between 0 and 9.  I figured that out using substring.  I am trying to do the same thing to check if the 4th character is a letter (upper or lower case).
So for the 0 to 9 I did:

```
dt.Select("(cats_act_typ like '" & acttyp & "') and (cats_order like '9MS%' AND substring(cats_order,4,1) >= 0 and substring(cats_order,4,1) <= 9)").CopyToDataTable
```

For the a to z, i tried using char.isletter, but that doesnt work in the select statement.

```
dt.Select("(cats_act_typ like '" & acttyp & "') AND (cats_order like '9MS%' and char.isletter(substring(cats_order,4,1)))").CopyToDataTable
```

That is not work. In sql I can easily do cats_order LIKE '9MS[a-Z]%'.

Comment: For the 4th character, try substring(cats_order,3,1) instead as first character will be at position 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already has data in memory, you can use c# language features.

```
var dataWithLetter = dt.AsEnumerable().
    Where(Function(row) row.Field(Of string)("cats_act_typ").Contains(acttyp)).
    Where(Function(row) Char.IsLetter(row.Field(Of string)("cats_order").ToCharArray()(3)).
    CopyToDataTable()
```